# cakePHP - Remember Search FIlters

Tags: search, cakephp, persistence

I have a cakePHP application with an advanded search section. When a user applys filters, they are lost when they navigate to an indivual record and then return to search page.

How / What is the best way to keep "memory" of this information and re apply it on page load?

Thanks Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try storing the search parameters in the session. Note that this isn't something that CakePHP can bake for you. You'll need to implement this yourself.

Comment: There is the Session component at your disposal, and if you look on google there is a bit on the topic

Answer (score 3):

Storing parameters in the session has some disadvantages when talking about storing searching criteria.

For example, using sessions is a good way for storing a shopping cart data or logged in user, because this state is the same when you open another new tab too.

But imagine when you apply some search filter, open a new tab with the same page, and then you see the same criteria you filled in previously opened page.

Comment: Nice answer! I've cleaned up the grammar a little bit; I hope you don't mind. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Good point. However, this is not actually an answer but rather a comment to the answer by Sander Marechal. Maybe you would like to add your alternative suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

In case this is helpful: I extensively use this Filter plugin for my searches/filtering:
https://github.com/lecterror/cakephp-filter-plugin

This plugin actually stores the search query across a session, so might be worth having a look at how it does it. In addition to storing a query - it also saves the filter query for each specific model without affecting the others.